# How do I print the value of a specific number of records in a loop / ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

In a data extension if I count the value using a loop then how can I print a specific number of records? As an example - if I have 10 records in my data extension and they all are showing using a loop but if I want to print only the 3rd record how do I do that using AMP script?

```
%%[

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @report_owner
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @report_owner = field(@row,"report_owner")
    
    set @report_owner2 = "Update done"

    ]%% <br>
    
    %%=v(@report_owner2)=%%
    
    %%[ next @i ]%%
            
    %%[ else   ]%%
    
    No rows found
    
    %%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for the value of your `@i` variable, which you autoincrement from 1 to `@rowcount`:

```ampscript
%%[
if @rowCount > 0 then
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
IF @i == 3 THEN
    var @report_owner
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
         set @report_owner = field(@row,"report_owner")
         set @report_owner2 = "Update done"
         Output(Concat('<br>',@report_owner2)
   ENDIF

next @i
            
else ]%%
    
    No rows found
    
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Similar solution can also be used if you want to limit the number of rows being retrieved:

```ampscript
%%[
set @maxRows = 3
if @rowCount > 0 then
if @rowCount < @maxRows 
then 
set @maxRows = @rowCount
endif
  for @i = 1 to @maxRows do
    var @report_owner
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
         set @report_owner = field(@row,"report_owner")
         set @report_owner2 = "Update done"
         Output(Concat('<br>',@report_owner2)
next @i
            
else ]%%
    
    No rows found
    
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, The second block of code works fine to limit the loop but what should I additionally do if I want to print only the value of 3rd position? Currently, I am getting all 5 records serially. Thanks!

Comment: And can I match if all the records are the same or not?

Comment: @MonowarHossain please see the code in first block where I have added the check if i == 3 - although checking for duplicates requires additional code

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for your help. One another thing, Can I compare the records like - if all the 3 records are exactly same then give a message else give another message. Thanks!